# Analysis on the output waveform from LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Simulated result from LT spice]
According to the data sheet of LT6202, it can be amplify frequency up to 100MHz, but when I input 4Mhz,the output become distorted, so any explanation about it?

Answer (score 1):

Opamps are also limited in the maximum slew rate they can drive. Looking at the LT6202 datasheet, the slew rate spec is typically 24V/us. That looks to be about the rate you are driving it in the simulation.

Try reducing the amplitude of the input signal. You should find that the distortion is reduced. The frequency is the same, but the maximum rate of change of voltage is smaller.

Comment: the slew rate of my spec about 302V/us using the formula 1.2(2pi)(40MHz)..is there any opamp can support this high slew rate? As my amplitude is fixed to 1.2Vpp.

Comment: Looks like liner have a couple. Try the parametric search on a few of the manufacture's websites.

Comment: yeah,I am searching a better circuit, but I still encounter the problem ,do you have any idea of the post equalization circuit?http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101736/construct-a-post-equalizing-circuit-to-compensate-imperfect-of-the-dac

Comment: @user37970 Maybe this one is OK http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6404f.pdf - it's a balanced output op-amp so it really is designed for high speed stuff. Sorry I mentioned the LT6202 - I should have checked it out a bit more in slew rate.

Comment: @user37970 slew rate is output related. If your circuit really has gain of 2 as in diagram, then to pass 40MHz without slew rate limit, OpAmp will need at least (Vin)(2Pi)(Av)(40MHz) or (1.2)(2Pi)(2)(40Mhz) = 603V/uSec.