# Op-amp with constant output voltage (Peak to Peak)

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, sine

I am new to opamps and am trying to amplify a variable frequency sine wave to a constant 5V peak-to-peak using opamps.
The input signal amplitude changes with frequency, but the opamp should always amplify to 5V peak-to-peak.

Aside: The input comes from an [AD9833](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjlqu7O2NjqAhUL-qQKHah-AGgQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftechnical-documentation%2Fdata-sheets%2FAD9833.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3yNNu7yNNcki_moK6ykRhN) waveform generator IC, and it's p2p is somewhere between 32-600mV. The output dfrequency ranges from about 1kHz to 2Mhz.

I could not find any information on how to accomplish this, or am just searching incorrectly.
I realize in a standard non-inverting amplifier circuit, I would just have to somehow control the feedback resistor value, meaning only the voltage divider on the inverting input would have to be controlled.
Kind of [like this variable-gain amplifier.](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-variable-gain-amplifier)

I was thinking about doing it the following way:

1. Buffer the output of the opamp so as to not disturb the signal
2. Convert buffered signal to an average DC signal using a capacitor and resistor
3. Use this DC voltage as feedback

However, this seems extremely complicated and I am no sure this will work at all.

Here is a sketch of it:
[image]

- Is there a standard configuration that will accomplish this without reinventing the wheel?
- Did I just come up with something silly and there is a more obvious way?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because the signal will be used elsewhere that needs a (fairly) constant peak-to-peak voltage regardless of frequency. 32-600mV is just too great a range to amplify to something convenient with a static gain.

Comment: You seem to be looking for what's called Automatic Gain Control (or AGC). Your concept is along the right path, though not quite right. For instance, your method of concerting input amplitude to some DC level cannot be performed with purely linear devices (ie  resistor and capacitor, that just makes a low or highpass filter). What you need is something like a diode peak detector. That would require a diode, resistor and capacitor. To make it work well though would require some careful thought.

Comment: @V.V.T yes, but it is actually attenuated depending on frequency. See https://ez.analog.com/dds/f/q-a/28266/ad9833-output-voltage-variation . Also, you will see if measuring the output.

Comment: Thank you for referring me to this useful post on Analog ez. I'll delete my comments, OK?

Comment: @namezero What kind of frequencies are you trying to pump out of this chip? Depending on how high they are, it's no wonder why the amplitude is dropping at high frequencies since whatever amplifier you're sticking on the output may not have a bandwidth high enough for your application. Especially if you are using opamps, which aren't exactly known for high bandwidth.

Comment: A peaked low pass filter will take care of the level drop at higher frequency. For low distortion the clock frequency should be much higher than the output frequency anyway, and then the small level variation is easily removed by the filter.

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3853.html

Comment: *The input signal amplitude changes with frequency* - how so?

Comment: @Andyaka Because of the attenuation of the DAC inside the chip, apparently.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The link is very interesting, especially the post-equalizing section. I am researching into this type of circuit now.

Comment: @Andyaka Given Bruces link, I am looking at your answer here now: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101736/construct-a-post-equalizing-circuit-to-compensate-imperfect-of-the-dac

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason so build an "anti" filter to compensate.

Comment: @Andyaka How did you get from sampling frequency to the value of the capacitor?

Comment: More detailed treatment by ADI of DDS DAC output sampling nature: https://ez.analog.com/dds/w/documents/3740/why-does-a-dds-need-a-reconstruction-filter , and two articles on Reconstruction Filter implementation (for AD9833 based DDS's): http://www.arrl.org/files/file/QEX_Next_Issue/May-Jun_2013/Fernandes_QEX_5_13.pdf and http://ascel.de/download/ae20125/ae20125_manual_en.pdf (page 45)

Comment: That capacitor value is taken from a picture in the MAXIM link posted by Bruce Abbott. I didn't calculate it but, in the past I've mimicked the DAC roll-off spectrum and added a HF shelf to compensate - all done within a SPICE environment.

Comment: Ok, after tinkering in LTSpice with resistor and capacitor values for a few hours I must ask:How to arrive at the capacitor value (mathematically) ?? I can get an acceptable response at 100khz, and either 1Mhz or 10Mhz, but not linear at both 1 an 10Mhz...